# can the nginx cofigured to pass though gzip content

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have a tomcat providing java web application, and nginx as a reverse proxy before it,
I turned on gzip compress feature of  tomcat,

at the two senarios:

1. browser---->nginx----->tomcat(download controller)
   download the file through nginx,no content-encoding response header found,but file can be download successful.
2. browser------->tomcat(download controller)
   download the file directly from tomcat, I can see content-encoding:gzip in this senario

my question is,  how can I configure nginx to provide "passthough effect",
in other words,  tomcat compress the file , and pass to nginx,
nginx donot process(means donot uncompress and compress again),
it just pass the zip content and the header "content-enoding:gzip" to browser

by the way, the actual nginx is from our product environment, I cant get it's configure current,
if it is necessary,I can provide it later

Comment: This was already answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/731247/nginx-reverse-proxy-how-to-pass-through-accept-encoding-header-to-back-end-se).

Comment: thank for your digging... I had searched but not found so clear explanation, let me try and told you,  pls post your comment as anwser so we can talk and I'll accept it if worded

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need GZIP functionality from Nginx then simply deactivate it in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file and set `gzip off;`